# Non-Default parameter follows default parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing

I keep getting an error message on my function parameters.

I've seen some other questions that are similar but I struggle to understand the answer and those people also had different situations which were more complex.

```
def check(user_answer='', list_of_blanks, letters):
    x = 0
    for letter in letters:
        if letter == user_answer:
            list_of_blanks[letters.index(user_answer)] = user_answer
            x += 1
    if x == 0:
        return False
    else:
        str(list_of_blanks)
    list_of_blanks = ''.join(list_of_blanks)
    return list_of_blanks
```

pycharm highlights "list_of_blanks, letters" (function parameters) and gives me the error which says:

```
Non-Default parameter follows default parameter.
```

If I try to default the parameter to an empty list like so:

```
list_of_blanks=[], letters=[]
```

then I get this error:

```
Default argument value is mutable.
```

Comment: The mutable thing is a warning

Comment: Read [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function-argument) about the different ways of defining function arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a non-positional argument (`param=value`) prior to positional arguments.

```py
def func(positional1, positional2, nonpositional=10)
```

This is due primarily to the fact you are not *required* to specify the name of non-positional parameters.

`func(10, 50, nonpositional=60)` == `func(10, 50, 60)`

Comment: You are not *required* to specify the name of any argument. The accurate thing to state is that you are not required to **pass** non-positional arguments **at all** and that will make a mess...

Comment: That's implied by the fact that they have default arguments.

Comment: OK I'm just saying that what you claim is the *primary* reason is not really an issue. because if specifying the name is the issue then even with the erroneous definition in the OP, we could call `check('answer', [1, 2], "abc")`. My point is that the real issue is that it can be omitted and then your positions change

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to switch positions of the arguments? Then you could just write:

```
def check(list_of_blanks, letters, user_answer=''):
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving an argument a default value makes it optional. You can't have optional arguments before non-optional ones because then it becomes unclear which slots you mean to assign and which you don't. You might be able to come up with a complex set of rules to determine how to interpret the arguments, but Python attempts to avoid unnecessary complexity, ambiguity, and counter-intuitive behavior.

You have a number of options available to work around this:

1. Move the default argument to the end of the list:

   ```
    def check(list_of_blanks, letters, user_answer=''):
   ```
2. Make all the other arguments optional as well:

   ```
    def check(user_answer='', list_of_blanks=(), letters=()):
   ```

   Using tuples, which are immutable, avoids the possibility accidental (and permanent) modification of the default lists.
3. Remove the default argument entirely:

   ```
   def check(user_answer, list_of_blanks, letters):
   ```

   Frankly this seems to be the best option in your case. Conceptually speaking, the most important arguments of a function come first. Unless your function has side-effects, making these arguments optional seems somehow deficient.
4. Make the other arguments required, but keyword-only:

   ```
   def check(user_answer='', *, list_of_blanks, letters):
   ```

   You will no longer be able to invoke the function as `check('abc', ['b', 'c'], ['a'])` because `list_of_blanks` and `letters` can no longer be specified as positional arguments. You must now invoke with keywords as `check('abc', list_of_blanks=['b', 'c'], letters=['a'])`. But now the first argument is unambiguously optional, so you can do things like `check(letters=['a'], list_of_blanks=['b', 'c'])`.

My personal preference, in decreasing order is 3, 4, 1, 2. I think your best bet is to have no optional arguments, but I can imagine you being in a phase where you'd want to play with keyword-only arguments regardless of the design implications.